# how can i get the date by 15 and 30 or 31 I'm creating an Overtime form i need the pay period to set in 15 or 30

Tags: c#

how can i get the date by 15 and 30 or 31 I'm creating an Overtime form i need the pay period to set in 15 or 30.

```
 Date Time pm5 = Date Time.Parse(date2)Add Days(15);
 string mystring5;
 mystring5 = pm5.To String("MM/dd/y y");
 textBox44.Text = mystring5;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the date by 15 and 30 or 31"? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Additionally, your code has spaces where there shouldn't be any and you seem to be missing periods. Please review your code before you post.

Comment: It is unclear what you say and your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: You probably want to use `TimeSpan`'s

Comment: im sory dont mind the spaces. im trying to get the pay period date. for example today is july 22 2014, in my program it should be july 31 ,2014 and if its august 1 it should be august 15.

Comment: Why did you write spaces all over the code?

Comment: im sory i wrote it that way because coz i tot it included in gramaar effect xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime payDay;
if(today.Day <= 15)
    payDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 15);
else
    payDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month));
```